# Checking Referential Integrity prior to Delete in APEX 20.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, referential-integrity, integrity, referential

When a user tries to delete a code/validation record, I would like to check to see if the code in that record has been used prior to the deletion attempt so I can display a message that is more meaningful than an Oracle constraint error.

For example:  "This code cannot be deleted because it has been referenced in a course record.  Please inactivate it instead."

Can anyone give me *general* advice on the approach to take?

My first thought was to create a dynamic action associated with the Delete button.  I think there is probably a better way, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the notion of catching errors *if* they happen using the application error handler
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmdb/editing-application-attributes.html#GUID-B744BE26-69B6-4084-A217-114CF05A5A4B

The [sample](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/aeapi/Example-of-an-Error-Handling-Function.html#GUID-2CD75881-1A59-4787-B04B-9AAEC14E1A82) provides detail on how to translate any known constraints to a more user-friendly message.

The danger with creating a DA along the lines of your suggestion is there may be a time difference, however small, between the check & display, and the actual delete attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You've said it - create a **validation**, they are designed for such a purpose. Make it a **Function body returning error text**. Write your piece of code and display a message. Something like

```
declare
  l_var number;
begin
  select d.blabla
    into l_var
    from detail_table d
    where ...;

  if l_var is not null then
     return ('This code can not be deleted etc.');
  end if;
end;
```